# best approach using cfthread

Tags: coldfusion, cfhttp

im looking at processing a query within a cfthread as the original data could be thousands of requests. Im looking at using cfthread 
so i can make it process in the background. I know there is alot of info on cfthread, but getting my head around it has been difficult.

what this all comes down to is a number of remote calls using cfhttp and whether they are in a single thread or should be on their own.

The remote calls could take between 5 - 10 seconds each, and the database updates are very minor, simply updating a true false value on the query
processing them.

```
<cfthread action="run" name="myThreadName" priority="high">
    <!--- do a query --->
    <cfloop query="myQuery">
        <!--- do a remote call --->
        <!--- process remote call response --->
        <!--- update local dbtables to indicate process is complete --->
        <!--- sleep using <cfset sleep(5000)> --->
    </cfloop>
</cfthread>
```

Or is this the more ideal basic use of cfthread for this basic process

```
<cfloop from="1" to="1000" index="idx">
    <cfthread action="run" name="myThreadName" priority="high">
        <!--- do a query --->
        <!--- do a remote call --->
        <!--- process remote call response --->
        <!--- update local dbtables to indicate process is complete --->
        <!--- sleep using <cfset sleep(5000)> --->
    </cfthread>
</cfloop>
```

Im trying to find the best balance so i dont crash my servers, but am also able to handle alot of these requests to fetch information from the external service, but im struggling to find which is the best direction, or if there is a better process all together to handle the remote requests on mass

thanks in advance

Comment: What's the purpose of the sleep?  Also, will this be a scheduled job or a user doing something?

Comment: The reason I put the sleep in there is if its taking a long time to do its task, i thought it gives it a break for a short period before resuming it. The purpose of this is to run behind the scenes with a loading page with an ajax ping that calculates how much more time is remaining. so to answer your question, something the user is doing, but presented nicely

Comment: Working in a place where we overwhelm our servers on occasion, your second approach appears to be the greater of two evils.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just spawn `n` threads and hope for the best. Too many threads will cause the CPU scheduler to switch context way too often and thus cause an overall slowdown. I also don't see why you would want the thread(s) to run in high(er) priority, given that there are other things on the machine that need CPU time. It would simply cause delay on other threads while the many high priority threads would still contest for CPU time among each other. There's also no need for a thread pause (sleep) then.

You need to make the best out of the two approaches. Consider something like this:

```
<cfset numberOfThreads              = 8>
<cfset numberOfRemoteCallsPerThread = 4> 

<cfloop from="1" to="#numberOfThreads#" index="threadIndex">

    <!--- do a query and split the number of records to process by dividing/offsetting --->

    <cfthread name="myThread_#threadIndex#">
        <!--- do a remote call --->
        <!--- process remote call response --->
        <!--- update local dbtables to indicate process is complete --->
    </cfthread>

</cfloop>
```

This will parallel your processing efficiently. Each thread will process a pre-determined set of records. To split the records, you could do something along the lines of:

```
SELECT
    <data to send>

WHERE
    <filter records to process>

LIMIT
    #((threadIndex - 1) * numberOfRemoteCallsPerThread)#, #numberOfRemoteCallsPerThread#
```

Whatever works best here depends on how you acquire the records that need processing. You might need to calculate the records before starting to loop etc.